# How to get rid of top black border on Text and TextArea in Firefox?

Tags: html, css

If you look at: [texasbruce.com/notes](http://texasbruce.com/notes)

You can notice there is black border on the top.

I already set the `border-color` to be blue, and `outline: none` but that is still there. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: it's a shadow in the box remove `box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #97c4fe;`

Comment: @JonathandeM. You can try in the browser to see if it works. I added the CSS myself.

Comment: The border color isn't blue, it's gray.

Comment: Set the border to a single color: style="border:1px solid blue;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-style:solid;` should be used to ensure it's not doing something strange.

This can all be accomplished in one rule though by saying `border: 1px solid blue;`

But also as mentioned in the comments above, the `box-shadow` might be creating an illusion of a darker border.

Comment: border-style is the one...Apparently Firefox renders it using its own ugly style...